Value of Spinner Clipped in Java Swing
I have a Spinner like below. when initialize the spinner there are not any issue. but when changing from one UI to other for edit and come back to earlier UI, value of Spinner is clipped. How to fix it.
CamSpinner privado getValiditySpinner() { 
   if (spinnerValidity == null) { 
      spinnerValidity = nuevo CamSpinner();   
      spinnerValidity.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 99, 1)); 
      spinnerValidity.setPreferredSize(Dimensión(35, 20));   
      spinnerValidity.setName(OutboxComponentNameConstants.DRUG_OUTBOX_LAST_D AY_OF_VALIDITY_SPINNER); 
      ValidationComponentUtils.setMessageKey(this.spinnerValidity, 
             DrugPackageInformationModel.Property.validityPeriod); 
   } 
   return spinnerValidity; 
} 


How to Use Spinners

private CamSpinner getValiditySpinner()
{
if (spinnerValidity == null)
{
spinnerValidity = new CamSpinner();
spinnerValidity.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 99, 1));
spinnerValidity.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 20));
 spinnerValidity.setName(OutboxComponentNameConstants.DRUG_OUTBOX_LAST_D 
  AY_OF_VALIDITY_SPINNER);
  ValidationComponentUtils.setMessageKey(this.spinnerValidity, 
  DrugPackageInformationModel.Property.validityPeriod);
}
 return spinnerValidity;

}

CamSpinner is my own class extends JSpinner

Read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and post the code from your comment in your question as formatted text. You should also try to post a [mcve] and add screen captures of your running app that show your problem.

Don't use setPreferredSize(). All Swing components will determine their own preferred size.

without setPrefferedSize(). How to control width as our desire? is there other way?

Swing components will determine the preferred size based on the Font and other properties of the component. Read the Swing tutorial on Specifying Spinner Formatting for ideas.
